# Avoid exec in instance variable definition

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I have a class in which I find myself define similar groups of variables many times, to the point that I believe it would be clearer if I were able to do so in a loop, as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initializeVariables()

    def initializeVariables(self):
        varnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        for var in varnames:
            exec("self.bg{0} = ttk.Frame(self.Frame)".format(var))
            exec("self.tb{0} = ttk.Entry(bg{0}, width=4)".format(var))
            exec("self.tb{0}.grid(row=i)".format(var))
```

I have more elements than this, this example is just meant to be illustrative. I would like to know:

1. Is there a way to accomplish this without using the `exec` function? I tried with `globals()`, but was not successful
2. Is doing this inadvisable? In my opinion, this makes the code easier to read, but I am not aware of typical conventions in this arena.

Comment: Just `setattr(self, 'tb' + var, ttk.Entry(self.Frame, width=4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to have individual object attributes for each widget. Creating attributes in a loop adds complexity without providing any real value in this case.

I suggest using a list or dictionary to store the references:

```
def initializeVariables(self):
    varnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    self.frames = {}
    self.entries = {}
    for var in varnames:
        self.frames[var] = ttk.Frame(...)
        self.entries[var] = ttk.Entry(...)
```

You can then later access them by their name. for example:

```
self.entries["c"].get()
```

Unless you need to access the frames in other parts of the code, you can use a local variable for the frame:

```
for var in varnames:
    frame = tk.Frame(...)
    self.entries[var] = ttk.Entry(frame, ...)
```

Comment: Accepting this answer based on the comments from Martijn Pieter's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options far better than `exec`:

- Use the [`setattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to set arbitrary attributes, given a string name for the attribute:

  ```
  varnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  for var in varnames:
      frame = ttk.Frame(self.Frame)
      entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=4)
      entry.grid(row=i)
      setattr(self, 'bg{0}'.format(var), frame)
      setattr(self, 'tb{0}'.format(var), entry)
  ```
- Use [`vars(self)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to access the instance namespace as a dictionary:

  ```
  namespace = vars(self)
  varnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  for var in varnames:
      frame = ttk.Frame(self.Frame)
      entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=4)
      entry.grid(row=i)
      namespace['bg{0}'.format(var)] = frame
      namespace['tb{0}'.format(var)] = entry
  ```
- Access the `self.__dict__` namespace directly:

  ```
  varnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  for var in varnames:
      frame = ttk.Frame(self.Frame)
      entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=4)
      entry.grid(row=i)
      self.__dict__['bg{0}'.format(var)] = frame
      self.__dict__['tb{0}'.format(var)] = entry
  ```

`vars(self)` is basically a forward-compatible and API-friendly way of spelling `self.__dict__`. I prefer using `setattr()` as this is compatible with classes using `__slots__` or hooking into `__setattr__`.

Setting attributes in a loop is fine (great even, as you are applying the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), using `exec` is not the best way to go about this however.

Do consider using a dictionary or list for repeated or grouped attributes. A dictionary or list makes it much easier to later access the whole group of elements in go:

```
frames = self.frames = {}
framed_entries = self.framed_entries = {}
varnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for var in varnames:
    frame = ttk.Frame(self.Frame)
    entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=4)
    entry.grid(row=i)
    frames['bg{0}'.format(var)] = frame
    framed_entries['tb{0}'.format(var)] = entry
```

Now you can access those same frames and entries with a simple loop over a dictionary, or directly address each one with a suitable key.

Comment: This is great, thank you! However, can you please address my second question too?

Comment: @wesanyer: there, added a sentence.

Comment: Perfect. I will accept this as an answer as soon as SO allows me too. Thanks again.

Comment: While I think this is a good, literal answe for the question that was asked, I think creating object attributes in this way will lead to hard-to-understand code.

Comment: @BryanOakley: true; using a dictionary or list lets you group the whole lot under a common 'namespace' separate from the instance.